# Holomorphic forms: a very basic notion

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a holomorphic (complex) manifold with:
$$(1)\quad
dim_{C}(M)=m.
$$

What I understand regarding a holomorphic form is that it is:

$$(2)\quad
\alpha^{(r,0)}=\frac{1}{r!}f_{\mu_1,\dots,\mu_r}(z)\space dz^{\mu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dz^{\mu_r}\in\Omega^{(r,0)}(M).
$$

Here the totally antisymmetric component functions are themselves holomorphic, and consequently entail only $z$ dependence.

Similarly an antiholomorphic form is given by:

$$(3)\quad
\beta^{(0,s)}=\frac{1}{s!}g_{\bar{\nu}_1,\dots,\bar{\nu}_s}(\bar{z})\space d\bar{z}^{\nu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge d\bar{z}^{\nu_s}\in\Omega^{(0,s)}(M),
$$
of course with the component functions being totally antisymmetric and antiholomorphic, consequently entailing only $\bar{z}$ dependence.

Taking the wedge of $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get the generic $(r,s)$ form:
$$(4)\quad
\omega^{(r,s)}=\frac{1}{r!s!}f_{\mu_1,\dots,\mu_r}(z)g_{\bar{\nu}_1,\dots,\bar{\nu}_s}(\bar{z})\space dz^{\mu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dz^{\mu_r}\wedge d\bar{z}^{\nu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge d\bar{z}^{\nu_s}\in\Omega^{(r,s)}(M).
$$

**Now a form is holomorphic if and only if $\bar{\partial}\omega=0$.**

If I begin with the form in $(2)$, which is holomorphic, then there is no problem seeing that $\bar{\partial}\alpha^{(r,0)}=0$, since this would involve $\bar{z}$ derivatives of the component functions which are clearly vanishing.

The problem arises when I begin with $\eta^{(p,q)}\in\Omega^{(p,q)}(M)$, require that it satisfy $\bar{\partial}\eta^{(p,q)}=0$, and try to get a quantity of the form $(2)$.

**Question 1:** Can someone please guide me along this proof?

**Question 2:** The following is particularly bothering me: consider $\gamma^{(p,m)}\in \Omega^{(p,m)}(M)$, then clearly $\bar{\partial}\gamma^{(p,m)}=0$ (for the wedge having $m+1$ barred indices is vanishing), but I cannot write it in the form $(2)$.

Comment: A holomorphic $p$-form $\alpha$ is a $(p, 0)$-form such that $\bar{\partial}\alpha = 0$. A $(p, q)$-form which is $\bar{\partial}$-closed is not usually called holomorphic.

Comment: Got that, thanks :)

Comment: You're wrong when you claim that a general $(r,s)$ form can be written as a wedge product of holomorphic and antiholomorphic forms. You need a general $C^\infty$ function for coefficients, not a sum of products of holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're trying to see that if you start with a $\bar\partial$-closed $(p,q)$ form, then it must be of type $(p,0)$? That's just not right, of course. Take the Kähler form or its powers, and you'll get $d$-closed (hence $\bar\partial$-closed) $(p,p)$ forms on any Kähler manifold.